# How to make your magento website load faster?

Tags: magento-1.9

Can you please tell me that how can i make my magento website load faster.

I have used the readymade template but its loading very slow, its my running site
this is my URL www.4happydays.com

its current loading time is 55.82 seconds whic is very much slow
my page size is 3.5 MB ..

I am new to magento and i dont know how to fix this issue.

Comment: What are your hosting specs right now?

Comment: Here is a long list https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25023/advice-on-optimizing-site-speed-where-to-start/55993#55993 ;)

Comment: no wonder ~ 301 other sites hosted on this server

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your server is responding very slowly to requests. Most of the load time in the short test I just did was waiting for the server to respond with a file. This is particularly bad, since you have many files in your theme. I would recommend upgrading your hosting platform immediately. I don't believe you can start working on optimization until your hosting is up to par. When you do get to that point, here are a couple links to help you out:

There is some great advice on Magento optimization in this question: [Advice on Optimizing Site Speed, where to start?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25023/advice-on-optimizing-site-speed-where-to-start)

You might also try using the Google PageSpeed tools here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2F4happydays.com%2F

Answer (score 0):

The longest 4 downloads I saw were javascript and css files. IF those can be moved to the bottom of the page you wouldn't leave users looking at a blank screen for 54 seconds. You could move those down, but there has to be something else going on to make any request take that long.

I second the opinion that you may need a better host - I would also make sure that your DNS configuration is correct, as there is large latency when leaving my ISP's network and trying to get to your server.

So, first things first -

- Make sure your DNS is correct, and possibly discuss routing issues with your hosting provider if they have decent service.
- Consider moving as many .css and .js file imports as possible to the footer.
- Get with a good Magento hosting company. I recommend [SimpleHelix](http://www.simplehelix.com/).
- Once the above are handled, if you really want to get more performance, switch to litespeed server instead of Apache.
- Implement parallelization for your assets. i.e. Create subdomains called js.4happydays.com, skin.4happydays.com, media.4happydays.com. Set those subs as the base urls in System->Config->Web->Unsecure & Secure.

The last two will only help once you get the basics down, start with dns and possibly a switch of hosting companies. Also, check that there aren't any conflicts between jQuery and Prototype, or any hanging imports.